# Read a char and a number in c

Tags: c, scanf

Im trying to read a char and number with the following:

```
char c;
char plus = '+';
int last;
if(scanf("%c%d",&c,&last)!=2 || last<0){
       printf("fail\n");
       return 1;
};

//trying to test it
if(plus==c){
    // code
}
```

But when I start the program, and type + 100 it throws "fail", as scanf wasn't successful. But if I just type 100 it works. Why does "fail" get printed when there are one char (+) and number (100) and why it doesn't  if I just type number.

Comment: I got no message with input `+ 100`. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZksV4WifjT6y81dC

Comment: You should check the value of `c` when "fail" is printed. It will become a clue for what is read.

Comment: the value of C is literally nothing and value of last is some random number (i guess memory adress ?) but there is nothing that should do such a thing.

Comment: "literally nothing"? Makes no sense. In `c`, there should be a number between -128 and 127 or between 0 and 255 on typical environment. The random number on `last` should be because it is uninitialized and failed to read.

Comment: The return value of `scanf` may also should be checked. Is it `1`? `0`? `EOF`?

Comment: Your code work perfectly fine in my system. Which compiler you are using?

Comment: You will probably find that with 100, you are getting c=1 and d=0.  Try +100 without a space to get c=+ and d=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine except for a ; try this it works :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(  )
{
  test();
 }

 int test()
 {
  char c;
  char plus = '+';
  int last;
  if ( scanf( "%c%d", &c, &last ) != 2 || last < 0 )
  {
    printf( "fail\n" );
    return 1;
  }   /////////////  YOU HAD UNNEEDED ; HERE
  else
  {
    printf( "\nyou entered:\n%c,%d", c, last );
    getchar(  );
  }
  //trying to test it
  if ( plus == c )
  {
// code
  }
}
```

Comment: which `;` you are referring to? And why have you added a space just before `%c%d` in `scanf()`? There is also no `return` for `main()` function.

Comment: @Pawan I added comment to code and removed space in scanf, just a bad (good) habit of mine.